# how to ignore jvm.config when running a mvn command?

Tags: java, maven, jvm

in the root there is a .mvn folder with jvm.config    with -XshowSettings:vm

if I run mvn -v
it outputs the VM Settings

I want to avoid it, but I cannot change the jvm.config

is there a way to override the jvm argument, how to unset XshowSettings:vm from command line?

Thanks